False interpretation of 95% confidence interval?
Disclaimer: I come from a science background and recently started a Master's degree in Statistics, so my current statistical knowledge comes from introductory university courses and the occassional MOOC.
I am confused about this interpretation of the 95% confidence interval given in the course notes of my professor in my class on Linear Models:

...
The 95% confidence interval of $\beta_1$ thus becomes $[0.376,0.640]$. Hence, with a probability
of 95% we expect that the regression coefficient $\beta_1$ is somewhere between $0.376$ and $0.640$. ...

This is actually the standard formulation used in the course notes - to me this seems like the infamous probabilistic interpretation of an observed confidence interval or am I missing a notion or a nuance here?

Once a confidence interval is realized, the probability of $\beta_1$ to be in the interval is either $1$ or $0.$

In the duplicate question the probability interpretation of the confidence interval is discussed. In a certain sense it is not wrong, but it depends on how the probability is interpreted. A confidence interval and a credible interval can both be seen to conditionally contain $\alpha %$ of the time the parameter. But, they relate to a different conditioning.
